# How to do a intercalate output with two inputs

Tags: vhdl

My problem is that i have two vectors, for example A and B. When the clock is one, I have to select the first elemente of the A vector, A(0), when clock is zero, B(0), and subsequently A(1), B(1), A(2), B(2)...

My actual code with some problems is that:

----------------------Top level Entity--------------

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity topentity is

    generic
    (
        DATA_WIDTH : natural := 8

    );

    port 
    (
        clk          : in std_logic;
        enable       : in std_logic;
        final_out    : out std_logic_vector(2*(DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0)
    );

end entity ;

architecture top of topentity is


signal A,B : std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);





component basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps is

    generic
    (
        DATA_WIDTH : natural := 8

    );

    port 
    (
        clk          : in std_logic;
        enable       : in std_logic;
        sr_one       : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        sr_two       : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        sr_out       : out std_logic_vector(2*(DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0)
    );
end component;

begin 


A <= "01010101";
B <= "10101010";

as: basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps port map (clk,enable,A,B, final_out(2*(DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0));



end top;
```

-------------------Component-----------------

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps is

    generic
    (
        DATA_WIDTH : natural := 8

    );

    port 
    (
        clk          : in std_logic;
        enable       : in std_logic;
        sr_one       : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        sr_two       : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        sr_out       : out std_logic_vector(2*(DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0)
    );

end entity ;


architecture rtl of basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps is


    signal sig_out  :std_logic_vector(2*(DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
    variable count  : integer := 0;
    variable count1 : integer := 0;

begin

    process (clk,enable,sr_one,sr_two,sig_out)

    begin

        if(enable = '0' or count = 16) then 
            count := 0;
            count1 := 0;
        else  
            if (clk'event and clk='1') then
                sig_out(count) <= sr_one(count1);

                count := count + 1;

            else --if (clk'event and clk='0') then--
                sig_out(count) <= sr_two(count1);
                count := count + 1;

            end if;

        end if;

        count1 := count1 + 1;   


    end process;

    sr_out <= sig_out;

end rtl;
```

------- This is a clock enter code here error that I cant solve---------

```
Info: Running Quartus Prime Analysis & Synthesis    Info: Version
   16.1.1 Build 200 11/30/2016 SJ Lite Edition  Info: Processing started: Tue Jan 10 11:44:53 2017 Info: Command: quartus_map
   --read_settings_files=on --write_settings_files=off teste -c teste Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which
   may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment
   NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best
   performance. Info (20030): Parallel compilation is enabled and will
   use 2 of the 2 processors detected Info (12021): Found 2 design
   units, including 1 entities, in source file vhdl1.vhd    Info (12022):
   Found design unit 1: basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps-rtl
    Info (12023): Found entity 1:
   basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps Info (12021): Found 2 design
   units, including 1 entities, in source file teste.vhd    Info (12022):
   Found design unit 1: topentity-top   Info (12023): Found entity 1:
   topentity Info (12127): Elaborating entity "topentity" for the top
   level hierarchy Info (12128): Elaborating entity
   "basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps" for hierarchy
   "basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps:as" Error (10818): Can't
   infer register for "sig_out[0]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41) because it does not
   hold its value outside the clock edge Info (10041): Inferred latch
   for "sig_out[0]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error (10818): Can't infer register
   for "sig_out[1]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41) because it does not hold its value
   outside the clock edge Info (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[1]"
   at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[2]"
   at Vhdl1.vhd(41) because it does not hold its value outside the clock
   edge Info (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[2]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33)
   Error (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[3]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41)
   because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[3]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error
   (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[4]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41)
   because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[4]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error
   (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[5]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41)
   because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[5]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error
   (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[6]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41)
   because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[6]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error
   (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[7]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41)
   because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[7]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error
   (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[8]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41)
   because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[8]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error
   (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[9]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41)
   because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[9]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error
   (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[10]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41)
   because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[10]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error
   (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[11]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41)
   because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[11]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error
   (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[12]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41)
   because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[12]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error
   (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[13]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41)
   because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[13]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Error
   (10818): Can't infer register for "sig_out[14]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41)
   because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "sig_out[14]" at Vhdl1.vhd(33) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[0]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[1]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[2]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[3]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[4]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[5]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[6]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[7]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[8]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[9]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[10]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[11]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[12]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[13]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[14]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[15]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[16]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[17]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[18]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[19]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[20]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[21]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[22]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[23]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[24]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[25]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[26]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[27]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[28]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[29]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[30]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Info
   (10041): Inferred latch for "count1[31]" at Vhdl1.vhd(37) Error
   (10818): Can't infer register for "count[0]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41) because
   it does not hold its value outside the clock edge Error (10818):
   Can't infer register for "count[1]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41) because it does
   not hold its value outside the clock edge Error (10818): Can't infer
   register for "count[2]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41) because it does not hold its
   value outside the clock edge Error (10818): Can't infer register for
   "count[3]" at Vhdl1.vhd(41) because it does not hold its value
   outside the clock edge Error (12152): Can't elaborate user hierarchy
   "basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps:as" Error: Quartus Prime
   Analysis & Synthesis was unsuccessful. 20 errors, 1 warning  Error:
   Peak virtual memory: 726 megabytes   Error: Processing ended: Tue Jan
   10 11:45:11 2017     Error: Elapsed time: 00:00:18   Error: Total CPU
   time (on all processors): 00:00:41
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to describe two sets of registers, one only operating on the rising edge and one only operating on the falling edge and muxing the registers to the output based on the level of clk. I did not see any reason why you need the count1 variable, so i removed it. Finally, i recommend to avoid asynchronous resets unless you really need the reset to be async.
I have only compiled the following code, no functional simulation performed, so i dunno if the code really does what you want to achive. But it might be a starting point for further community discussion.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps is
    generic
    (
        DATA_WIDTH : natural := 8

    );
    port 
    (
        clk          : in std_logic;
        enable       : in std_logic;
        sr_one       : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        sr_two       : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        sr_out       : out std_logic_vector(2*(DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0)
    );
end entity ;

architecture rtl of basic_shift_register_with_multiple_taps is
    signal sig_out_one  :std_logic_vector(2*(DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
    signal sig_out_two  :std_logic_vector(2*(DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
begin
    process (clk)
        variable count  : integer := 0;
    begin
        if (clk'event and clk='1') then
            if enable = '0' then 
                count := 0;
            else
                sig_out_one(2*count) <= sr_one(count);

                if count<sr_one'high then
                    count := count + 1;
                else
                    count := 0;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;   
    end process;

    process (clk)
        variable count  : integer := 0;
    begin
        if (clk'event and clk='0') then
            if enable = '0' then 
                count := 0;
            else
                sig_out_two(2*count+1) <= sr_two(count);

                if count<sr_two'high then
                    count := count + 1;
                else
                    count := 0;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;   
    end process;

    with clk select
        sr_out <= sig_out_one when '1',
                  sig_out_two when others;

end rtl;
```